# Loading Full PHP File with jquery script in it

Tags: php, jquery

**The Problem**
I have a project i am working on, and i am using the structure below:

Main File (index.php)

  Sub folder

    Sub Sub folder
      Php file with it's Jquery code


All sub sub folder files are loaded through jquery load with the code below

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub_sub_menu', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 //uri = subfolder/subsubfolder/i.php {Assuming}
 uri = $(this).attr('uri')
 $('.system_viewport').load(uri)
})
```

When i click on a certain menu bar item, it loads the php page just fine, and i can perform all the functionalities within the php page on my Main File (index.php) page, when i load other files by clicking on them in the menu bar they load just fine, the problem is when i try to go back to a file that was previously loaded, hell is let loose as most of the click events refuse to trigger.

**My Thinking** 
The first time the file was loaded it load the jquery functions to the DOM when loaded again it still load the functions to DOM there by creating some sort of clash or something...

Comment: I don't quite get the point of implementing essentially anchor tags manually with click events. What is the context with that?

Comment: @TimSeguine Part of the requirement is that they don't want the user to know which file they are accessing, also they prefer the please wait system loading notification to the whole file reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could keep track of the uris that have been loaded before:

```
let visitedUrls = [];
$(document).on('click', '.sub_sub_menu', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  //uri = subfolder/subsubfolder/i.php {Assuming}
  uri = $(this).attr('uri');
  if(visitedUrls.indexOf(uri) === -1) {
    $('.system_viewport').load(uri);
    visitedUrls.push(uri);
  } else {
    $('.system_viewport').load(uri + '?excludejs=1');
  }
});
```

On the php-side of the app you can then exclude the JS files from the content based on `if($_GET['excludejs'] == '1')` or something like that?!

Comment: Thanks allot let me try implementing it and see.